# Show that the maximum function of a continous function is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be compact, let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and define the function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by

$g(x):=\max\{\phi(x,y)|y\in D\}$

Show that $g$ is continous.

Unfortunately I have no clue where to start. Do I need to use compact property of $D$?

Comment: Compactness guarantees that $g$ is well defined.

Comment: This has been answered earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.
Show that $\phi_x:y\mapsto \phi(x,y)$ is continuous.

Step 2.
Recall that a continuous map $D\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and achieves its bounds, assuming $D$ is compact. Conclude that the function $g$ is well-defined.

Step 3.
Show that $g$ is continuous.

Have a go, and if you have trouble explain which steps aren't working out.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! Is (1) true because $\mathbb{R}^m$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$ is the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$. The elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are not of this form so $\mathbb{R}^n\not \subset \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$. However, you may wish to embed $\mathbb{R}^m\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$, in which case, fine but you need to know that this inclusion is continuous too.

Comment: Ok then I don't know how to proceed. Could you tell me how to show that $\phi_x$ is continuous?

Comment: You should know the definition of continuity. Recall what the definition says. Now apply it to $g$, what does it mean to say $g$ is continuous. Finally, think about whether you believe what it says. If you do, try to think about why you believe it. If you don't know why it is true, then recall what else you know about $g$ and repeat.

Comment: It means that for any sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to $x$, $g(x_n) \rightarrow g(x)$. Now do I need to use the definition that $g$ is the maximum function of $\phi_x$?

Comment: According to the steps I gave above, you need to prove continuity of $\phi_x$ and $g$. When doing the latter, yes, you use the definition of $g$, i.e. $g(x)=\max \phi_x$.